# merge content of 2 text files into a third text file - line by line

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am working on a trivia script in php and I got a problem that can't get past it.

I have two txt files, one with questions and other with answers.

The questions file looks like this:

```
"How many arms a person has" =>
"How many legs a person has" =>
```

The answers file looks like this:

```
  "2",
  "2",
```

Is it possible to move or copy the lines from answers file to questions file to get something like this in a single file?

```
"How many arms a person has" => "2",
"How many legs a person has" => "2",
```

Comment: Why on earth would you resort to batch if you are already working in a higher level language like php?

Comment: @dbenham my original question was refering to php, but since i managed to get it working with batch, it got modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming content of file 1 is a.txt and content of file 2 is b.txt and result is expected in c.txt, try in windows batch file (say `merge.bat`):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (a.txt) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set a[!i!]=%%a
)

set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (b.txt) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set b[!i!]=%%a
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do echo !a[%%i]! is from !b[%%i]!>> c.txt
ENDLOCAL
```

Edited answer to resolve multiple looping issue.

Explanation:

`setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` Enables the delayed environment variable expansion until the matching endlocal command is encountered, regardless of the setting prior to the setlocal command.

This enables translation of:

`!a[1]! is from !b[1]!` for each line to its respective conetent filled in array `a` and `b` which are populated from files `a.txt` and `b.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the outup of c.txt
`"How many arms a person has" => "2"
"How many arms a person has" => "2"
"How many legs a person has" => "2"
"How many legs a person has" => "2"`

every question is posted twice.

Comment: For every question in the questions file it posts a line with every answer from the answers file.

Comment: The updated code workes perfect for the example in my question but does it has any limitations to how many lines the files should have, because when I test it on files with 18000 lines each, it freezes and no file is generated or populated.

Comment: oh, i have not stress tested it sorry.

Comment: I have added an ENDLOCAL macro, could you check this out and see if it resolves your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this in php :

```
<?php

$questions = array();
$answers = array();

$questionFile = fopen("path/to/questions.txt", "r");
$answerFile = fopen("path/to/answers.txt", "r");

while($row = fgets($questionFile)) {
    $questions[] = $row;
}

while($row = fgets($answerFile)) {
    $answers[] = $row;
}

fclose($questionFile);
fclose($answerFile);

if(count($questions) === count($answers)) {
    $mergingFile = fopen("path/to/thirdFile.txt", "w+");

    foreach($questions as $key => $question) {
        fwrite($mergingFile, $question . $answers[$key] . "\r\n");
    }

    fclose($mergingFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple task with my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScrpit/batch script that performs regular expression search/replace on text. JREPL.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jrepl "^.*" "$0+' '+stdin.ReadLine()" /j /f questions.txt /o merged.txt <answers.txt
```

The command above reads input both from the file specified by the `/F` option and also from the redirected stdin. The `/J` option treats the replacement string as JScript code that is executed for each match.

If the questions might span multiple lines, then you can clarify the search string to get the corrrect result:

```
jrepl "^.*==>$" "$0+' '+stdin.ReadLine()" /j /f questions.txt /o merged.txt <answers.txt
```